# Slimer Js webpage evaluation

Tags: slimerjs

```
var webpage = require('webpage').create();

webpage
  .open('http://example.com')
  .then(function(){
    var someContent = webpage.evaluate(function () {
        return document.querySelector("#aDiv").textContent;
    });

     console.log(someContent);
  });
```

It is called once, but my web page is dynamically changing. How can I intercept every change?

Answer (score 0):

if it's changed due to ajax calls, you should use onResourceReceived to observe changes